# what is response time in terms of discrete event simulation

Tags: events, simulation, discrete-mathematics

Can some one explain what exactly response time is, with respect to discrete event simulation of a store,hospital or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How quickly can the system deal with a customer/patient in your two specific cases.

Comment: can you put that in terms of a formula for better mathematical explanation.

Comment: `begin_service_time - arrival_time` if you are concerned with how quickly you get to the customer/patient, or `departure_time - arrival_time` if you want to focus on total time they are in the system.